# Express Route stops working after a set amount of Angularjs Post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express

I'm having some trouble getting AngularJS, Express and MongoDB to work together. I'm still new to all three of these and trying to make a simple 'to do' app and toggle a check button to mark something complete. I able to execute a function on the angular side that will do a $http 'POST' to an express route that ultimately updates a MongoDB record. I am able to do this 6 times before it stops working. I can see in the inspector console that the function is still being called, but somewhere between the $http 'POST' and executing the route, it doesn't register it anymore. I no longer see console.log activity on my Express server from the route.

Here is my toDoController.js

```
toDoApp.controller('ToDoController', function ToDoController($scope, $http, itemsData) {

    ... other functions

    $scope.toggleToDo = function(item) {
        console.log('updateToDo()');
        console.log(item);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/todolist/toggle_to_do',
            data: item
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('success post');
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
        }); 
    }
}
```

Express app.js route

```
app.post('/todolist/toggle_to_do', todolist.toggleToDo);
```

Express route.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID; // used to create ObjectID when looking for the record

var collection
var database

// Connect to Database ------------------------------------------------
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('\033[96m + \033[39m connected to mongodb');

            collection = db.collection('to_do_list');
            database = db;

            }
        );

    // update record
    exports.toggleToDo = function(req, res) {
        console.log("-toogle 'To Do item' completed status");

        console.log(req.body.completed);
        console.log(req.body._id);

        collection.update({
                _id: new ObjectID(req.body._id)
            }, 
            {
                $set: { 
                    completed: req.body.completed 
                } 
            },
            function(err) {
                if(err) console.warn("Could not write to DB");
                else console.log("Item successfully updated!");
            }
        );
    };
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Express has the ability to throttle requests. Any chance that's configured on your server?

Comment: You may be running out of connections (it's hard to tell from the way you've organized your code in your question). You shouldn't be opening/closing a new connection for each request. Generally, you'll only need to open one connection in a NodeJs application, and reuse it.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html

Comment: I don't believe I have changed any configurations, will it throttle requests by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I didn't end my response.

res.end();

```
exports.toggleToDo = function(req, res) {
    console.log("-toogle 'To Do item' completed status");

    console.log(req.body.completed);
    console.log(req.body._id);

    collection.update({
            _id: new ObjectID(req.body._id)
        }, 
        {
            $set: { 
                completed: req.body.completed 
            } 
        },
        function(err) {
            if(err) console.warn("Could not write to DB");
            else console.log("Item successfully updated!");
        }
    );
    res.end();
};
```

Comment: you should consider to end the response in your update callback, so the client will be sure everything went successfully (or reply with error if error has occured)